# phpseclib - sftp with rsa key Login failed

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib and I am trying to login in SFTP using an RSA key:

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('134.XXX.XXX.XXX');

$Key = new Crypt_RSA();
$passphrase='XXXXX';
$Key->setPassword($passphrase);
$Key->loadKey(file_get_contents('ssh/id_rsa'));

if (!$sftp->login('root', $Key)) {
    echo $sftp->getLog();
}
```

But the login fail I don't know why

The logs are

> <- 00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:4f:70:65:6e:53:53:48:5f
> SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_ 00000010
> 38:2e:33:70:31:20:55:62:75:6e:74:75:2d:31:0d:0a  8.3p1 Ubuntu-1..
>
> -> 00000000  53:53:48:2d:32:2e:30:2d:70:68:70:73:65:63:6c:69  SSH-2.0-phpsecli 00000010
> 62:5f:31:2e:30:20:28:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:6c:2c:20  b_1.0 (openssl,
> 00000020  62:63:6d:61:74:68:29:0d:0a                       bcmath)..
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.233, network: 0.0001s) 00000000  bc:a4:29:26:61:c2:a7:72:86:7c:5e:bc:4f:89:72:d6  ..)&a..r.|^.O.r.
> 00000010  00:00:00:7e:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d
> ...~diffie-hellm 00000020
> 61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67  an-group-exchang
> 00000030  65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d
> e-sha256,diffie- 00000040
> 68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:2d:65:78  hellman-group-ex
> 00000050  63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66
> change-sha1,diff 00000060
> 69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70  ie-hellman-group
> 00000070  31:34:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68
> 14-sha1,diffie-h 00000080
> 65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70:31:2d:73:68  ellman-group1-sh
> 00000090  61:31:00:00:00:29:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32
> a1...)rsa-sha2-2 000000a0
> 35:36:2c:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c  56,rsa-sha2-512,
> 000000b0  73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c:73:73:68:2d:64:73:73:00
> ssh-rsa,ssh-dss. 000000c0
> 00:00:e9:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65  ...aes128-ctr,ae
> 000000d0  73:31:39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d
> s192-ctr,aes256- 000000e0
> 63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61  ctr,aes128-cbc,a
> 000000f0  65:73:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36
> es192-cbc,aes256 00000100
> 2d:63:62:63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:74  -cbc,blowfish-ct
> 00000110  72:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:33
> r,blowfish-cbc,3 00000120
> 64:65:73:2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63  des-ctr,3des-cbc
> 00000130  2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72:32:35:36:2c:61:72:63:66
> ,arcfour256,arcf 00000140
> 6f:75:72:31:32:38:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32  our128,twofish12
> 00000150  38:2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32
> 8-ctr,twofish192 00000160
> 2d:63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d  -ctr,twofish256-
> 00000170  63:74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63
> ctr,twofish128-c 00000180
> 62:63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:62  bc,twofish192-cb
> 00000190  63:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63
> c,twofish256-cbc 000001a0
> 2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:00:00:00:e9  ,twofish-cbc....
> 000001b0  61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31:39
> aes128-ctr,aes19 000001c0
> 32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72  2-ctr,aes256-ctr
> 000001d0  2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:31
> ,aes128-cbc,aes1 000001e0
> 39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:62  92-cbc,aes256-cb
> 000001f0  63:2c:62:6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:74:72:2c:62
> c,blowfish-ctr,b 00000200
> 6c:6f:77:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:2c:33:64:65:73  lowfish-cbc,3des
> 00000210  2d:63:74:72:2c:33:64:65:73:2d:63:62:63:2c:61:72
> -ctr,3des-cbc,ar 00000220  63:66:6f:75:72:32:35:36:2c:61:72:63:66:6f:75:72  cfour256,arcfour
> 00000230  31:32:38:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63
> 128,twofish128-c 00000240
> 74:72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:74  tr,twofish192-ct
> 00000250  72:2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:74:72
> r,twofish256-ctr 00000260
> 2c:74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:32:38:2d:63:62:63:2c  ,twofish128-cbc,
> 00000270  74:77:6f:66:69:73:68:31:39:32:2d:63:62:63:2c:74
> twofish192-cbc,t 00000280
> 77:6f:66:69:73:68:32:35:36:2d:63:62:63:2c:74:77  wofish256-cbc,tw
> 00000290  6f:66:69:73:68:2d:63:62:63:00:00:00:39:68:6d:61
> ofish-cbc...9hma 000002a0
> 63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  c-sha2-256,hmac-
> 000002b0  73:68:61:31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61
> sha1-96,hmac-sha 000002c0
> 31:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d  1,hmac-md5-96,hm
> 000002d0  61:63:2d:6d:64:35:00:00:00:39:68:6d:61:63:2d:73
> ac-md5...9hmac-s 000002e0
> 68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61  ha2-256,hmac-sha
> 000002f0  31:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2c:68
> 1-96,hmac-sha1,h 00000300
> 6d:61:63:2d:6d:64:35:2d:39:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d  mac-md5-96,hmac-
> 00000310  6d:64:35:00:00:00:04:6e:6f:6e:65:00:00:00:04:6e
> md5....none....n 00000320
> 6f:6e:65:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  one.............
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT (since last: 0.0552, network: 0.0544s)
> 00000000  31:7c:5d:0a:48:88:65:bb:5a:77:fd:66:0e:56:69:5a
> 1|].H.e.Zw.f.ViZ 00000010
> 00:00:00:e6:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39:2d:73  ....curve25519-s
> 00000020  68:61:32:35:36:2c:63:75:72:76:65:32:35:35:31:39
> ha256,curve25519 00000030
> 2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:40:6c:69:62:73:73:68:2e:6f  -sha256@libssh.o
> 00000040  72:67:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73
> rg,ecdh-sha2-nis 00000050
> 74:70:32:35:36:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68:61:32:2d  tp256,ecdh-sha2-
> 00000060  6e:69:73:74:70:33:38:34:2c:65:63:64:68:2d:73:68
> nistp384,ecdh-sh 00000070
> 61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70:35:32:31:2c:64:69:66:66  a2-nistp521,diff
> 00000080  69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75:70
> ie-hellman-group 00000090
> 2d:65:78:63:68:61:6e:67:65:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36  -exchange-sha256
> 000000a0  2c:64:69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d
> ,diffie-hellman- 000000b0
> 67:72:6f:75:70:31:36:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64  group16-sha512,d
> 000000c0  69:66:66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72
> iffie-hellman-gr 000000d0
> 6f:75:70:31:38:2d:73:68:61:35:31:32:2c:64:69:66  oup18-sha512,dif
> 000000e0  66:69:65:2d:68:65:6c:6c:6d:61:6e:2d:67:72:6f:75
> fie-hellman-grou 000000f0
> 70:31:34:2d:73:68:61:32:35:36:00:00:00:41:72:73  p14-sha256...Ars
> 00000100  61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c:72:73:61:2d:73
> a-sha2-512,rsa-s 00000110
> 68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:2c  ha2-256,ssh-rsa,
> 00000120  65:63:64:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:6e:69:73:74:70
> ecdsa-sha2-nistp 00000130
> 32:35:36:2c:73:73:68:2d:65:64:32:35:35:31:39:00  256,ssh-ed25519.
> 00000140  00:00:6c:63:68:61:63:68:61:32:30:2d:70:6f:6c:79
> ..lchacha20-poly 00000150
> 31:33:30:35:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d  1305@openssh.com
> 00000160  2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31
> ,aes128-ctr,aes1 00000170
> 39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74  92-ctr,aes256-ct
> 00000180  72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65
> r,aes128-gcm@ope 00000190
> 6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d  nssh.com,aes256-
> 000001a0  67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00
> gcm@openssh.com. 000001b0
> 00:00:6c:63:68:61:63:68:61:32:30:2d:70:6f:6c:79  ..lchacha20-poly
> 000001c0  31:33:30:35:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d
> 1305@openssh.com 000001d0
> 2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:31  ,aes128-ctr,aes1
> 000001e0  39:32:2d:63:74:72:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d:63:74
> 92-ctr,aes256-ct 000001f0
> 72:2c:61:65:73:31:32:38:2d:67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65  r,aes128-gcm@ope
> 00000200  6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:61:65:73:32:35:36:2d
> nssh.com,aes256- 00000210
> 67:63:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00  gcm@openssh.com.
> 00000220  00:00:d5:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f
> ...umac-64-etm@o 00000230
> 70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d  penssh.com,umac-
> 00000240  31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e
> 128-etm@openssh. 00000250
> 63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35  com,hmac-sha2-25
> 00000260  36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f
> 6-etm@openssh.co 00000270
> 6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d  m,hmac-sha2-512-
> 00000280  65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c
> etm@openssh.com, 00000290
> 68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70  hmac-sha1-etm@op
> 000002a0  65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36
> enssh.com,umac-6 000002b0
> 34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d  4@openssh.com,um
> 000002c0  61:63:2d:31:32:38:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63
> ac-128@openssh.c 000002d0
> 6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36  om,hmac-sha2-256
> 000002e0  2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c:68
> ,hmac-sha2-512,h 000002f0
> 6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61:31:00:00:00:d5:75:6d:61:63  mac-sha1....umac
> 00000300  2d:36:34:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e
> -64-etm@openssh. 00000310  63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:2d:65:74:6d  com,umac-128-etm
> 00000320  40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61
> @openssh.com,hma 00000330
> 63:2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f  c-sha2-256-etm@o
> 00000340  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d
> penssh.com,hmac- 00000350
> 73:68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65  sha2-512-etm@ope
> 00000360  6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68
> nssh.com,hmac-sh 00000370
> 61:31:2d:65:74:6d:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63  a1-etm@openssh.c
> 00000380  6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:36:34:40:6f:70:65:6e:73
> om,umac-64@opens 00000390
> 73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:75:6d:61:63:2d:31:32:38:40  sh.com,umac-128@
> 000003a0  6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:2c:68:6d:61:63
> openssh.com,hmac 000003b0
> 2d:73:68:61:32:2d:32:35:36:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73  -sha2-256,hmac-s
> 000003c0  68:61:32:2d:35:31:32:2c:68:6d:61:63:2d:73:68:61
> ha2-512,hmac-sha 000003d0
> 31:00:00:00:15:6e:6f:6e:65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:40:6f  1....none,zlib@o
> 000003e0  70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e:63:6f:6d:00:00:00:15:6e:6f
> penssh.com....no 000003f0
> 6e:65:2c:7a:6c:69:62:40:6f:70:65:6e:73:73:68:2e  ne,zlib@openssh.
> 00000400  63:6f:6d:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
> com.............
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_REQUEST (since last: 0.0005, network: 0s) 00000000  00:00:06:00:00:00:08:00:00:00:10:00
> ............
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_GROUP (since last: 0.2671, network: 0.2657s)
> 00000000  00:00:01:01:00:c6:6d:2c:18:83:04:2b:44:3c:fe:0a
> ......m,...+D... 00000010
> 10:a9:de:4f:21:20:cb:37:5e:93:a5:0c:ef:11:ad:d1  ...O! .7^.......
> 00000020  b8:f8:ed:99:23:bb:e9:e2:31:dd:c9:f2:41:62:1e:6f
> ....#...1...Ab.o 00000030
> c0:dc:32:0b:78:30:86:e4:19:f0:d7:46:39:4c:ec:de  ..2.x0.....F9L..
> 00000040  3e:7a:e0:9e:87:95:6d:b1:ed:4e:51:7a:96:61:f6:36
>
> > z....m..NQz.a.6 00000050  1e:a7:45:ec:b5:84:1b:b8:b7:a1:2a:a7:ec:e0:cb:26  ..E.......*....&
> > 00000060  2d:64:62:ae:52:7e:1d:45:62:db:85:3e:71:2c:aa:c8
> > -db.R~.Eb..>q,.. 00000070  97:1c:17:a3:d4:d3:a9:81:87:a3:e7:8a:0f:fb:f4:6c  ...............l
> > 00000080  94:a4:ea:a0:9c:d4:e8:19:73:86:2e:8d:e4:ec:5a:64
> > ........s.....Zd 00000090
> > ed:78:c4:52:43:00:ed:47:27:a3:65:ff:e4:1f:5e:f1  .x.RC..G'.e...^.
> > 000000a0  13:25:03:8f:78:8d:e6:ec:c6:b9:3d:77:b6:43:5f:33
> > .%..x.....=w.C_3 000000b0
> > 3a:ed:77:ff:c5:ee:20:d1:66:e9:76:6b:ce:ff:7a:03  :.w... .f.vk..z.
> > 000000c0  99:60:1c:ad:4e:1d:74:6c:59:a5:c0:77:53:75:f7:6f
> > .`..N.tlY..wSu.o 000000d0
> > 2c:c9:2f:72:22:85:4a:17:99:02:f3:f3:24:ac:56:99  ,./r".J.....$.V.
> > 000000e0  6c:c6:aa:a3:61:20:51:eb:7a:f7:ef:b3:f1:99:ff:d5  l...a
> > Q.z....... 000000f0  a0:66:1b:6b:8e:cf:b8:e7:1c:25:6d:f5:27:5b:93:2f
> > .f.k.....%m.'[./ 00000100  c6:2b:34:3b:ef:00:00:00:01:05
> > .+4;......
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_INIT (since last: 0.0444, network: 0.0001s) 00000000  00:00:01:01:00:a4:f1:94:ec:07:7c:90:a8:9f:e4:a5
> ..........|..... 00000010
> ea:d8:5d:02:be:4f:a3:d3:c6:3d:52:b7:55:fb:82:95  ..]..O...=R.U...
> 00000020  1b:0a:f8:1b:18:ec:69:34:de:00:0e:22:ac:4e:32:78
> ......i4...".N2x 00000030
> a7:6c:46:b1:86:70:de:5f:22:c5:7c:d8:e0:c4:53:c0  .lF..p._".|...S.
> 00000040  87:04:a5:c5:25:8c:7b:df:8d:41:b5:c5:75:10:e8:27
> ....%.{..A..u..' 00000050
> be:93:d5:e8:6e:6a:f1:67:b5:8d:a3:be:1c:24:9a:51  ....nj.g.....$.Q
> 00000060  0f:cf:65:92:44:95:3f:8e:8c:16:f9:95:df:e3:dc:06
> ..e.D.?......... 00000070
> f1:24:c0:5d:ab:09:1a:9a:9f:61:aa:06:eb:c1:5f:26  .$.].....a....*&
> 00000080  20:1d:0e:53:55:98:71:97:87:4d:26:96:e5:64:15:ef
>
> ..SU.q..M&..d.. 00000090
> e2:55:9f:3b:96:c1:5f:81:52:b8:a9:a8:96:b1:ab:1a  .U.;..*.R.......
> 000000a0  20:d9:52:ee:61:dd:88:c7:97:e8:91:f8:d3:87:28:d4
> .R.a.........(. 000000b0
> 5a:2c:a8:ed:7f:01:eb:62:7e:12:38:fa:7e:56:46:c8  Z,.....b~.8.~VF.
> 000000c0  f4:49:0f:30:e1:2d:16:68:e1:4a:2b:b6:a8:53:cd:28
> .I.0.-.h.J+..S.( 000000d0
> 68:f1:9f:22:32:89:21:f8:29:f9:80:14:e5:d6:c8:66  h.."2.!.)......f
> 000000e0  10:9a:c6:49:45:99:65:79:41:b7:b3:b1:db:ce:43:21
> ...IE.eyA.....C! 000000f0
> c2:21:76:29:f7:52:1b:de:db:29:0f:50:a9:4b:93:af  .!v).R...).P.K..
> 00000100  a4:21:a1:39:12                                   .!.9.
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_GEX_REPLY (since last: 0.0858, network: 0.0857s)
> 00000000  00:00:01:97:00:00:00:07:73:73:68:2d:72:73:61:00
> ........ssh-rsa. 00000010
> 00:00:03:01:00:01:00:00:01:81:00:c8:71:64:45:27  ............qdE'
> 00000020  79:6b:c5:27:e0:26:38:ad:ba:fd:4a:bd:d6:29:19:1b
> yk.'.&8...J..).. 00000030
> 2a:7d:68:30:66:f1:50:49:bc:82:9f:92:d7:0d:a5:25  *}h0f.PI.......%
> 00000040  8c:38:c6:7a:0d:7c:eb:17:de:24:56:5a:04:89:31:42
> .8.z.|...$VZ..1B 00000050
> d5:77:28:9f:cc:e6:80:1a:33:ab:d4:98:ff:c1:a7:03  .w(.....3.......
> 00000060  04:bc:9e:a6:dd:db:75:00:fa:cd:b4:b1:18:9c:d6:bc
> ......u......... 00000070
> f0:f0:b2:f8:0a:85:2b:3c:a7:c6:9f:98:b0:1e:55:88  ......+.......U.
> 00000080  8f:b3:17:26:fd:11:5b:00:fe:f1:cf:cf:85:6b:7e:9f
> ...&..[......k~. 00000090
> 20:45:2b:b5:71:f0:10:ba:64:a6:bf:62:01:13:ae:d5   E+.q...d..b....
> 000000a0  fd:0f:37:54:26:47:03:33:d5:b3:b5:a0:0d:54:33:55
> ..7T&G.3.....T3U 000000b0
> d0:49:33:78:96:48:93:33:5b:e9:40:4a:0c:ac:1a:eb  .I3x.H.3[.@J....
> 000000c0  7b:5a:2d:8b:2d:6c:4d:7e:81:87:df:4f:7c:88:8b:a3
> {Z-.-lM~...O|... 000000d0
> e9:60:ce:4a:b9:a7:dc:f8:80:1a:5a:f5:d9:0a:21:9f  .`.J......Z...!. 000000e0  2c:4a:84:02:6e:f8:4f:5a:49:f7:18:64:9d:7a:02:bb  ,J..n.OZI..d.z.. 000000f0  87:df:b3:3f:32:15:28:86:0b:45:b0:0b:62:de:66:89  ...?2.(..E..b.f. 00000100  3d:d5:ca:74:ca:b9:d1:af:ab:37:81:b8:86:37:dc:62  =..t.....7...7.b 00000110  d7:50:b0:84:2a:39:b0:38:ab:e2:2c:76:67:4c:99:78  .P..*9.8..,vgL.x 00000120  9c:80:f9:4b:f6:ab:40:9d:4c:98:1d:9f:7d:e2:13:de  ...K..@.L...}... 00000130  9c:14:3c:5e:1f:d6:77:9d:ad:c2:85:ec:79:50:e2:2b  ...^..w.....yP.+ 00000140  05:cc:7d:08:00:01:a0:ca:d5:de:68:0b:17:2c:48:6f  ..}.......h..,Ho 00000150  9f:4f:ca:16:c0:90:a9:49:df:83:08:69:1c:6d:4d:70  .O.....I...i.mMp 00000160  1a:57:0b:d6:0a:84:46:3f:ce:f8:95:3a:cf:54:af:7c  .W....F?...:.T.| 00000170  60:7e:4f:ae:c4:85:01:5b:cd:44:84:ac:b6:5b:ec:31`  ~O....[.D...[.1
> 00000180  a4:90:1d:d9:4f:2c:db:73:45:ed:06:5e:73:a8:d4:2f
> ....O,.sE..^s../ 00000190
> c1:73:a8:01:81:88:c7:dd:44:87:f5:00:00:01:00:35  .s......D......5
> 000001a0  c2:cb:f1:4d:e9:1a:98:3e:99:b5:10:6c:28:5e:e6:9a
> ...M...>...l(^.. 000001b0
> 33:b1:71:56:a9:72:fe:ff:d0:db:04:5b:b8:c3:75:f0  3.qV.r.....[..u.
> 000001c0  12:4c:ce:2e:3a:5f:48:4f:78:7e:00:17:35:9e:25:80
> .L..:_HOx~..5.%. 000001d0
> 80:40:5c:b8:15:f6:a4:df:50:fc:25:fa:02:60:63:82  .@.....P.%..`c. 000001e0  61:06:00:36:1f:1d:2f:ee:d1:43:51:94:9d:ec:b9:be  a..6../..CQ..... 000001f0  a4:87:0f:80:54:01:73:3e:1c:c1:b5:b0:69:bd:4d:db  ....T.s>....i.M. 00000200  87:f2:db:65:4f:4c:d3:46:4b:8d:5e:e6:d2:4c:17:89  ...eOL.FK.^..L.. 00000210  ff:88:cd:30:77:98:1f:c5:df:58:af:0d:b9:69:81:aa  ...0w....X...i.. 00000220  7e:be:4b:ba:a9:04:4d:41:50:cf:bb:85:24:e5:01:cc  ~.K...MAP...$... 00000230  35:10:16:ea:b7:d7:a9:4a:02:0a:7f:28:ef:ac:e1:c1  5......J...(.... 00000240  43:a6:64:ed:e5:12:04:e4:99:5a:06:f3:b4:35:9f:4a  C.d......Z...5.J 00000250  81:ce:c5:4e:3f:b6:5b:28:cb:8b:25:fc:5d:fe:03:d9  ...N?.[(..%.]... 00000260  e2:d2:6c:46:35:ee:c5:8b:f4:5a:e4:40:40:e2:16:31  ..lF5....Z.@@..1 00000270  5b:26:3e:3b:c2:79:51:59:97:6f:50:53:a0:bd:83:ed  [&>;.yQY.oPS.... 00000280  1e:6f:d1:53:5f:54:b4:e1:d4:dc:ee:8e:77:5c:96:4e  .o.S_T......w\.N 00000290  27:ec:da:b4:25:a7:31:a4:9f:85:b8:e9:5c:b1:4e:00  '...%.1.....\.N. 000002a0  00:01:94:00:00:00:0c:72:73:61:2d:73:68:61:32:2d  .......rsa-sha2- 000002b0  32:35:36:00:00:01:80:33:0a:63:2e:31:ca:c9:8e:b6  256....3.c.1.... 000002c0  3c:04:e3:28:38:14:2f:a7:6b:10:1f:e6:fa:3e:92:22  ...(8./.k....>." 000002d0  80:81:48:db:0f:86:a3:b3:8b:db:cd:ee:47:2f:5c:58  ..H.........G/\X 000002e0  28:9a:be:d8:74:ba:16:db:d3:12:e6:31:7d:a6:17:eb  (...t......1}... 000002f0  ed:28:e5:9d:a5:ff:3b:a1:49:a0:98:5a:1c:a6:62:5b  .(....;.I..Z..b[ 00000300  db:ed:e9:f7:86:10:e9:09:61:58:32:b8:fa:42:cb:9a  ........aX2..B.. 00000310  4f:ef:80:d9:62:73:1a:d0:d3:e0:a7:0e:3a:8b:04:04  O...bs......:... 00000320  5c:00:6e:14:b3:da:ab:41:46:4e:b6:49:92:ec:c9:62  \.n....AFN.I...b 00000330  9c:2d:a5:24:69:cc:53:44:58:58:1b:ef:4f:27:7d:b9  .-.$i.SDXX..O'}. 00000340  27:99:5d:56:b9:03:c0:c0:34:0d:92:1d:b5:b3:26:29  '.]V....4.....&) 00000350  da:24:cf:35:75:1f:5a:59:0d:96:92:2b:70:c2:a3:ff  .$.5u.ZY...+p... 00000360  1b:1a:de:d7:78:17:6a:c4:e6:a8:86:b2:91:c8:6a:60  ....x.j.......j` 00000370
> 4e:ad:6e:70:37:10:91:4a:ab:cb:fb:dd:9e:fd:85:66  N.np7..J.......f
> 00000380  19:c2:c4:f9:ae:6e:b8:71:60:f0:a0:d8:af:4f:98:eb
> .....n.q`....O.. 00000390
> a7:bf:95:e1:77:b3:5a:51:57:85:a8:b8:59:82:2b:37  ....w.ZQW...Y.+7
> 000003a0  7a:52:0f:f1:98:d8:fc:18:f9:41:dc:9e:9e:27:ec:1c
> zR.......A...'.. 000003b0
> e8:1a:88:64:18:da:2f:ae:7a:d5:19:97:1c:3b:f6:a7  ...d../.z....;..
> 000003c0  b9:51:a9:ab:8b:27:69:04:d3:ec:66:eb:bf:0d:e0:4f
> .Q...'i...f....O 000003d0
> a7:54:2b:08:07:61:55:18:c0:f7:0f:f7:b8:9a:c0:58  .T+..aU........X
> 000003e0  d8:03:0c:a0:56:1a:ac:6a:e5:20:95:f4:25:c2:81:15  ....V..j.
> ..%... 000003f0  d1:b1:f4:b4:d0:12:f1:69:76:f1:da:94:f9:f7:2b:a0
> .......iv.....+. 00000400
> 41:b0:66:f4:10:fc:fc:8c:2f:74:5d:73:ea:3c:9e:1d  A.f...../t]s....
> 00000410  b2:e9:d2:e0:d0:63:9c:15:91:c2:8f:9d:03:7c:1c:e7
> .....c.......|.. 00000420
> 21:5e:3a:c6:fe:58:12:20:dc:36:02:d8:8a:c0:ca:fa  !^:..X. .6......
> 00000430  e4:4b:75:62:81:39:d7                             .Kub.9.
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0542, network: 0.0001s)
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS (since last: 0.0002, network: 0.0001s)
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST (since last: 0.0011, network: 0s) 00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68
> ....ssh-userauth
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT (since last: 0.2091, network: 0.2089s)
> 00000000  00:00:00:0c:73:73:68:2d:75:73:65:72:61:75:74:68
> ....ssh-userauth
>
> -> NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_REQUEST (since last: 0.0004, network: 0.0001s) 00000000  00:00:00:04:72:6f:6f:74:00:00:00:0e:73:73:68:2d  ....root....ssh- 00000010
> 63:6f:6e:6e:65:63:74:69:6f:6e:00:00:00:04:6e:6f  connection....no
> 00000020  6e:65                                            ne
>
> <- NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_FAILURE (since last: 0.1189, network:
> 0.1186s) 00000000  00:00:00:09:70:75:62:6c:69:63:6b:65:79:00        ....publickey.

Comment: Yes indeed I can

Comment: What format is the key in? phpseclib does not support password protected `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----` keys since OpenSSH's custom bcrypt implementation is far to slow to implement with PHP. And since it's a custom bcrypt implementation that OpenSSH uses neither https://www.php.net/crypt or http://php.net/password-hash can be used. You'd have to implement it in pure-PHP which is just not fast enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an openssh private key starting with  `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`

These keys are not compatible with phpseclib

I had to convert it using:

> ssh-keygen -p -N "" -m pem -f /path/to/key

Comment: The keys actually are supported - it's just _encrypted_ keys of that format that are not supported. FWIW!